# "Error downloading or extracting tarball"?

Tags: sd-card, noobs, failure

To prevent failures from shutting down abruptly, I always type `sudo shutdown -h now`. On this occasion something didn't work for me and I had to simply unplug the Raspberry Pi.

Now I get a this error:

> mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector ______, nr ___, cmd
>   response 0x900, card status 0x200b00

[image]

Of course tried searching for the error code and wondered if my card is dead. 
It is a verified SD card (16GB by Kingston). Is there is a tool that would allow me to use it again?

[image]

I have completed full format of SD card and I wonder if my SD card is likely to be working fine or is inevitably corrupted. In each case I would like to know how to extend it's life/probability of success.

---

Related links:

- http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=20659
- http://forum.brewpi.com/discussion/comment/1772
- http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#SD_cards

Comment: Despite all the horror posts on this Forum, SD cards are not that fragile (at least the quality cards). There may only be a couple of cells damaged. Just reimage and try again.

Comment: I removed the section about the warranty of the SD card in my edit.  Customer support would be a better candidate to ask that.

Comment: Thanks for edits - now it is much more clear. As an excuse: I was editing post couple of times, attaching photos, referring to links, etc..

Comment: I'm curious what's wrong here as well; I'm having the same issue. I hope you found a solution

Comment: I've ordered a new card form here - http://swag.raspberrypi.org/collections/frontpage/products/noobs-8gb-sd-card (now sold out) - using the faulty one in a camera (with success)